# Challenging Issue : Loading models from external directory in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration, model

I have been trying to figure out a way to load models from different directory other than "application/models" directory.
I want to load my model from "application/modules".

I have tried the instructions by extending CI_Loader by following instructions provided in

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/103276/#

but it is giving me error "Unable to locate the specified class: Model.php" whereas my core "Model.php" is there under "system/core" folder.

Even ,I have also tried to load model using

```
 $this->load->model (APPPATH.'modules/mymodel.php');
```

but no success.

**UPDATE:**

I want my model loader to behave like this :

```
$this->load->module('mymodel')
```

and

$this->mymodel->mymodelmethod() !!

```
NOT like:    $this->load->models('mymodel')
```

Is there any way i could load models from outside the `"application/modules"` folder ?
Please advise .Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that the article your referencing relates to an older version of codeigniter. To extend a core class in the latest version you have to place the extended class into your `application/core` folder not `application/library`. Check the **[offical documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)**

Comment: Thanks @Jeemusu My loader class is already in application/core with the name My_Loader.php (extending CI_Loader)

Comment: Can you post your MY_Loader class? and the line of code you are using to load your model?

Comment: Thanks @Jeemusu .I created My_Loader.php under "application/core" and i am using the code as provided in this link ( http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/103276/# )

Comment: The line i am using to load the external model is : $this->load->model(APPPATH.'modules/m_mymodel.php');

Comment: I have upgraded my version but still having the same error :(

Comment: What have you done exactly? What you should be doing is taking the `Model()` function from your `system/core/Loader.php` class and using that as a base for your MY_Loader class.

Comment: I noticed you started a bounty. Was my answer of no help? If you have any questions about it please ask.

Comment: i am also unable to understand how can you assign your bounty points when you don't have enough

Comment: @Jeemusu.i tried as instructed but it didn't help.

Comment: @raheelshan I am working on project and trying to find a way to use my own modules like this we do this in CI without using "$this->load->model('my_model')".I have instead of "models" directory ,i have "modules".Is there anyway i can use models outside "models" directory (i.e using modules directory amd NOT "models")??

Comment: @Bilal I have tested the code from my answer (read latest comments) and it works fine for loading models from a folder called `modules`.

Comment: @Jeemusu how are calling the model functions using MY_Loader?

Comment: @Bilal Khalid, I will update my answer one last time. It would of been nice if you outlined what you wanted seven days ago, as what you are talking about now is nothing like what you originally posted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem  is that **[the code you reference](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/103276/#)** is for an older version of codeigniter. In older versions of codeigniter the `CI_Model` class was named `Model`. As the class `Model` doesn't exist in the latest version of php you are getting the error:

`Unable to locate the specified class: Model.php`

The part of the code where this is happening is towards the end (line 114):

```
    if ( ! class_exists('Model'))
    {
        load_class('Model', FALSE);
    }
```

If you check your system/core/Loader.php you will see that in the version of codeigniter you are using this has been replaced with:

```
    if ( ! class_exists('CI_Model'))
    {
        load_class('Model', 'core');
    }
```

You need to re-write the MY_Loader.php to make it compatible with the version of codeigniter you are using, presumably 2.1.

The best way to do this would be to grab the **[Codeigniter 2.1 version of the core Loader.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Loader.php)** and use the `model()` method from it as a base for re-writing your MY_Loader.php.

Something to bare in mind when re-writing your `MY_Loader.php` is that constructors also changed in later versions of codeigniter, so your MY_Loader class should look something like this:

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function model($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

More details on extending core classes can be found in the **[Codeigniter Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)**

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed you changed your functionality, so I updated the answer. You can create a whole new loader and base it off the core CI_Model class, although it seems like a lot of effort when you could just extend the model loader and be done.

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    protected $_ci_module_paths     = array();
    protected $_ci_modules          = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_ci_module_paths = array(APPPATH);
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->_ci_classes = array();
        $this->_ci_loaded_files = array();
        $this->_ci_models = array();
        $this->_ci_modules = array();
        $this->_base_classes =& is_loaded();

        $this->_ci_autoloader();

        return $this;
    }

    public function module($module, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
    {
            if (is_array($module))
            {
                    foreach ($module as $babe)
                    {
                            $this->$module($babe);
                    }
                    return;
            }

            if ($module == '')
            {
                    return;
            }

            $path = '';

            // Is the $module in a sub-folder? If so, parse out the filename and path.
            if (($last_slash = strrpos($module, '/')) !== FALSE)
            {
                    // The path is in front of the last slash
                    $path = substr($module, 0, $last_slash + 1);

                    // And the module name behind it
                    $module = substr($module, $last_slash + 1);
            }

            if ($name == '')
            {
                    $name = $module;
            }

            if (in_array($name, $this->_ci_modules, TRUE))
            {
                    return;
            }

            $CI =& get_instance();
            if (isset($CI->$name))
            {
                    show_error('The module name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: '.$name);
            }

            $module = strtolower($module);

            foreach ($this->_ci_module_paths as $mod_path)
            {
                    if ( ! file_exists($mod_path.'modules/'.$path.$module.'.php'))
                    {
                            continue;
                    }

                    if ($db_conn !== FALSE AND ! class_exists('CI_DB'))
                    {
                            if ($db_conn === TRUE)
                            {
                                    $db_conn = '';
                            }

                            $CI->load->database($db_conn, FALSE, TRUE);
                    }

                    if ( ! class_exists('CI_Model'))
                    {
                            load_class('Model', 'core');
                    }

                    require_once($mod_path.'modules/'.$path.$module.'.php');

                    $module = ucfirst($module);

                    $CI->$name = new $module();

                    $this->_ci_modules[] = $name;
                    return;
            }

            // couldn't find the model
            show_error('Unable to locate the module you have specified: '.$module);
    }


    public function add_package_path($path, $view_cascade=TRUE)
    {
        $path = rtrim($path, '/').'/';

        array_unshift($this->_ci_library_paths, $path);
        array_unshift($this->_ci_model_paths, $path);
        array_unshift($this->_ci_module_paths, $path);
        array_unshift($this->_ci_helper_paths, $path);

        $this->_ci_view_paths = array($path.'views/' => $view_cascade) + $this->_ci_view_paths;

        // Add config file path
        $config =& $this->_ci_get_component('config');
        array_unshift($config->_config_paths, $path);
    }

    public function remove_package_path($path = '', $remove_config_path = TRUE)
    {
        $config =& $this->_ci_get_component('config');

        if ($path == '')
        {
            $void = array_shift($this->_ci_library_paths);
            $void = array_shift($this->_ci_model_paths);
            $void = array_shift($this->_ci_module_paths);
            $void = array_shift($this->_ci_helper_paths);
            $void = array_shift($this->_ci_view_paths);
            $void = array_shift($config->_config_paths);
        }
        else
        {
            $path = rtrim($path, '/').'/';
            foreach (array('_ci_library_paths', '_ci_model_paths', '_ci_module_paths', '_ci_helper_paths') as $var)
            {
                if (($key = array_search($path, $this->{$var})) !== FALSE)
                {
                    unset($this->{$var}[$key]);
                }
            }

            if (isset($this->_ci_view_paths[$path.'views/']))
            {
                unset($this->_ci_view_paths[$path.'views/']);
            }

            if (($key = array_search($path, $config->_config_paths)) !== FALSE)
            {
                unset($config->_config_paths[$key]);
            }
        }

        // make sure the application default paths are still in the array
        $this->_ci_library_paths = array_unique(array_merge($this->_ci_library_paths, array(APPPATH, BASEPATH)));
        $this->_ci_helper_paths = array_unique(array_merge($this->_ci_helper_paths, array(APPPATH, BASEPATH)));
        $this->_ci_model_paths = array_unique(array_merge($this->_ci_model_paths, array(APPPATH)));
        $this->_ci_module_paths = array_unique(array_merge($this->_ci_module_paths, array(APPPATH)));
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array_merge($this->_ci_view_paths, array(APPPATH.'views/' => TRUE));
        $config->_config_paths = array_unique(array_merge($config->_config_paths, array(APPPATH)));
    }

    private function _ci_autoloader()
    {
        if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') AND file_exists(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/autoload.php'))
        {
            include(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/autoload.php');
        }
        else
        {
            include(APPPATH.'config/autoload.php');
        }

        if ( ! isset($autoload))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Autoload packages
        if (isset($autoload['packages']))
        {
            foreach ($autoload['packages'] as $package_path)
            {
                $this->add_package_path($package_path);
            }
        }

        // Load any custom config file
        if (count($autoload['config']) > 0)
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            foreach ($autoload['config'] as $key => $val)
            {
                $CI->config->load($val);
            }
        }

        // Autoload helpers and languages
        foreach (array('helper', 'language') as $type)
        {
            if (isset($autoload[$type]) AND count($autoload[$type]) > 0)
            {
                $this->$type($autoload[$type]);
            }
        }

        // A little tweak to remain backward compatible
        // The $autoload['core'] item was deprecated
        if ( ! isset($autoload['libraries']) AND isset($autoload['core']))
        {
            $autoload['libraries'] = $autoload['core'];
        }

        // Load libraries
        if (isset($autoload['libraries']) AND count($autoload['libraries']) > 0)
        {
            // Load the database driver.
            if (in_array('database', $autoload['libraries']))
            {
                $this->database();
                $autoload['libraries'] = array_diff($autoload['libraries'], array('database'));
            }

            // Load all other libraries
            foreach ($autoload['libraries'] as $item)
            {
                $this->library($item);
            }
        }

        // Autoload models
        if (isset($autoload['model']))
        {
            $this->model($autoload['model']);
        }

        // Autoload modules
        if (isset($autoload['module']))
        {
            $this->module($autoload['module']);
        }
    }

}
```

You can use the above in your controller via:

```
$this->load->module('test_module');
$this->test_module->method();
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to explain but how can i load models from "application/modules"?The above strategy assumes that your directory and methods are within "models" directory

Comment: exactly... that is why you extend the core class so you change the model() methods code. You could probably just change `$mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php'` to `$mod_path.'modules/'.$path.$model.'.php'` and it should work as expected.

Comment: @Jeesmusu.Thanks.Here are the steps i have done but no success.1)I updated my "application/core/MY_Loader.php " with yours. 2) I tried to load my modelloader method to load my model located in (application/modules/m_secur.php) using :  $this->load->model('m_secur'); BUT GOT this error: Unable to locate the model you have specified: m_secur

Comment: Does your modules folder have permissions set? It will probably need `chmod 555`

Comment: If you change the path in your MY_Loader.php back to `models` instead of `modules` it should work, if it does that would be a good indicator that your `modules` folder has no permissions set.

Comment: @Jeemusu.I have checked the file permissions and seem ok to me.if i will change back to models,then there is no point to have "modules" directory.The behavior is same as $this->load->models('mymodel') and NOT $this->load->models('mymodel') and $this->mymodel->mymodelmethod !!

Comment: @Jeemusu.Thanks for such a Brilliant solution.Just few notes to add here.I dont think $name and $path are doing much in above code.Instead,$path can be taken as method parameter to specify subdirectories within the Loader (i.e if(isset($path)){require_once($mod_path.'modules/'.$path.'/'.$module.'.php');}else{ require_once($mod_path.'modules/'.$module.'.php');}   ).Thanks for your time.

Comment: The $path is used in the cases when your module is in a sub-folder inside your modules folder. The $name parameter can be set to allow you to access the module from a different name. I.E. your module is called `test_module`, but you want to access it using `$this->test->method()`. In that case you can set the $name param to a string `test`.

Comment: @Jeemusu.Brilliant ! 10/10 :)

Answer (score 1):

If i am getting your problem correctly , you have to initialize the instance of CI.

Example :-

In your external file do this :-

```
    class modules
    {
        var $CI;

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
        }

        function retrieve_data()
        {
          // Load Model
          $this->CI->load->model('YOUR MODEL NAME'); // Give the name of your model that you want to laod
        }
     }
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks @Sushil.modules is my folder name under application folder:)

Comment: @BilalKhalid Did it hepled you ?? If YES , then accept this answer 
If NO , let me know the issue that you are facing now

Comment: No it didnt.Please read my question again.I am trying to load model from external directory.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question the answer lies here.

[Moduler Extension](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/overview)

download it and install according to the instructions. then you can simply access any thing with these steps.

In your controller load the module like this.

```
$this->load->module('pages');
```

Make sure you have a directory `Modules` under application. And your Module `pages` should exist there. `Pages module` can have controller , models , views , helpers , config and libraries etc.

Now you need to call model. Here is how you can do it.

```
$this->pages->model->test_model->get_test_data();
```

Also you should note that loading module loads all the resources.

Comment: Are you sure that this refers to models as well and not only to controller methods??What about accessing modules outside "application" directory??

Comment: @BilalKhalid i am sure of that i have used it already. And you should note you are using php not Visual Studio. If you want to use modules outside application directory then you will have to do some manual configuration.

Comment: could you modify your code to explain it detail?What configurations i would need to change?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, try this

```
public function setPackagePaths($path, $view_cascade=TRUE, $model_cascade=TRUE, $library_cascade=TRUE, $helper_cascade=TRUE) { 
        $path = rtrim($path, '/').'/';

        ///$this->_ci_view_paths = $this->_ci_library_paths = $this->_ci_model_paths = array();
        $this->_ci_library_paths = array($path.'libraries/' => $library_cascade) + $this->_ci_library_paths ;
        $this->_ci_helper_paths = array($path.'helpers/' => $helper_cascade) + $this->_ci_helper_paths ;
        $this->_ci_model_paths = array($path.'models/' => $model_cascade) + $this->_ci_model_paths ;
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array($path.'views/' => $view_cascade) + $this->_ci_view_paths;



        // Add config file path
        $config =& $this->_ci_get_component('config');
        array_unshift($config->_config_paths, $path);
    }
```

Its a hardcore way to update this function to Loader Class. But works fine.